# Jquery - .val and add custom attribute value

Tags: jquery, attributes

In Jquery Can I append and add attr like: for this:

```
  <li class="test" ln="7" >
```

How do I get the value of r into this:

```
$('#box input[name= _def]').val( JUNK) + "VALUE OF ln";
```

Can I get the value of custom attribute 'ln' appended after the val ?

Comment: for what purpose do you intend to use the `attr` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `data-` attribute to hold your data:

```
<li class="test" data-ln="7" >
```

You can add the attribute with jQuery using `.data()`:

```
$li.data('ln', 7);
```

And you can use `.data()` to extract it (and automatically convert common data types):

```
var ln = $li.data('ln');
```

Comment: Is this supported across all the browsers?

Comment: @user1022521: Sure, I don't see why not. I think jQuery resorts to using `setAttribute()` for browsers that don't support HTML5 data attributes.

Comment: It is with the HTML5 shiv, or jQuery fixes it for you via .data() defaults.

Comment: My problem is not adding the attribute - but getting the value of this attribute in this line $('#box input[name= _def]').val( JUNK) + "VALUE OF ln";

Comment: can I get the value of the atribute after .val in jquery? even if I add as a data attribute I am not able to add this value of attribute to the line I wanted

Comment: @user1022521: What do you hope to achieve by adding them together?

Comment: I want to add them together for building part of url, is there a way to add it the way i wanted in JQUERY any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use **HTML-5 data attributes** for `validated HTML`..

This is `supported by all the browsers.`

```
<li class="test" data-ln="7" >

var val = $('li.test').data('ln');
```

For such cases you can use `.data()` method to extract the value.

If you still want to follow the same syntax that you are using **which is not recommended**, you can use the `getAttribute` method

```
   var val = document.getElementsByClassName('test').getAttribute('ln');
```